# Qn-print and write all array element using recursion in JavaScript cuz i'm new to the concept of recursion i couldn't able to figure out the problem

Tags: javascript, recursion

Here is my code and I know there is some mistake in my code but I'm
new to the concept of recursion.
I think there is a problem cuz I tried to implement the same code as
the C language.
I want my answer to read and print array by using recursion
And I tried to convert the c code into javascript, c++ code into
javascript and lastly in python code into javascript.

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var l = a.length;
var num = 0;

function printArr(a, i, l){
  for(var i=0; i<l; i++){
    num = a[i];
  }
  if(i>=l){
    return 0;
    printArr(a, i+1, l);  //<I think in this section I'm having a problem.>
  }
}

printArr(a, 0, l); 
console.log(num);
```

Comment: `> enter code here` what is this for? Please format your code properly.

Comment: sorry bro I'm new on StackOverflow i don't know how to properly use StackOverflow @kiner_shah

Comment: Probably, you want to put `printArr` before return. Also, the `for` loop seems weird, what is it supposed to do?

Comment: it supposed to iterate through array elements one by one. i dont know bro i just tried to convert the code from c language to javascript and i'm just abeginner with the javascript language

Comment: Maybe you should post your C code for reference.

Comment: I just want to print array elements by using recursion in javascript. Bro, I'm learning all by myself so I don't know how to properly make code working @kiner_shah

Comment: here is the reference link https://codeforwin.org/2016/03/c-program-to-print-elements-of-array-using-recursion.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for that for loop.

Your `printArr` call should be outside `if` statement.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var l = a.length;
//var num = 0; // not needed

function printArr(a, i, l) {
  // Base condition - to break out of recursion
  // check if index is out of array bounds, if yes return
  if (i >= l) {
    return;
  }

  // if not, print the array element at that index
  console.log(a[i]);

  // call the recursive function with next consecutive index
  printArr(a, i + 1, l);
}

printArr(a, 0, l);
```

Comment: You see it is very similar to C.

Comment: I love u bro thank u soo much. cuz u helped me. thank u again for ur help @kiner_shah

Comment: @AlphaMomin, if my post was useful, please consider upvoting.

Comment: i want to vote u bro but it showing me that u can't cast a vote need 15 reputation but again thank u cuz I'm feeling stuck at least from 5 days at the same problem

Comment: You may vote later once you have sufficient reputation ;-)

Comment: yeah, bro why not but as a beginner currently I'm facing a lot of problems. I want become self-taught developer maybe i can make it happen in near future

Answer (score 1):

Another method would allow us to avoid mucking about with indices at all, destructuring the input array and checking whether the first element is empty:

```js
const printArr = ([x, ...xs]) => {
  if (x == null) return null
  console .log (x)
  return printArr (xs)
}

printArr ([1, 2, 3])
```

I would personally prefer to write this as a single expression, like this:

```js
const printArr = ([x, ...xs]) => 
  x == null ? null : (console .log (x), printArr (xs))
```

Comment: thank u for ur help but right now as a beginner I prefer to write my code as simple as I can so I can understand it